# flutter web WhatsApp web won't open

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I  have a button when the button is clicked it should open WhatsApp on whatsAppW Web with the given phone number, and I'm using [url_luancher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

here i want to navigate to whatsApp Url but when i click on the button it won't work.

```
 _launch(url) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      print("Not supported");
    }
  }

OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () => 
   _launch(Uri.parse(
  'whatsapp://send?text=sample text&phone=00000000000'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open via `whatsapp web` you can use whatsapp `api` call and use `url_launcher` to open it in browser

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+00000000000000&text=iwanttotestit
```

Comment: hey Sparsh, I appreciate your answer, i want to ask what if the user using the phone and want to open WhatsApp app?

Comment: i think it will work with phone too, but also you can add checks for different devices.
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}